# Can anyone identify this Australian tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image: Australian Native Tree - Wrights Hill]

This tree is found in the Wrights Hill area on the New South Wales/Australian Capital Territory border.
Bark at breast height is curled and dense, becoming less dense at height.

Comment: Eucalyptus, but which one?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. For tree identification we need close-up pictures of leaves and flowers — this is especially true for a large group like the eucalypts! Thank you for taking the [tour], you may also find it helpful to go through the [help] starting with [ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The changes in the bark makes it look like Eucalyptus melliodora (Yellow box).

[image]

Locations recorded are in this link. [http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=sp&name=Eucalyptus~melliodora](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=sp&name=Eucalyptus%7Emelliodora)

Some photos of this tree can be seen at:
http://www.nccma.vic.gov.au/sites/default/files/publications/nccma-41853_-_box-gum_grassy_woodland_identification_10-11_web_0.pdf